# Button height with custom background

Tags: android

I have two buttons, one of them has default style, another has custom background drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/green" />
</shape>
```

In the end buttons look like this:

[image]
So default button is somehow smaller than button with custom background, though they have same properties:

```
    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_button_rounded_green"
            android:text="Positive"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Negative"/>
```

It seems that custom background changes minHeight. How can I make this buttons look the same?

Answer (score 0):

`btn_default_normal.9.png` is the default Image set to default `Button` widget in Android from any specific platform. Find this file in you `SDK` installation and copy to your `res` folder.

Path to find `android-sdk\platforms\android-APILEVEL\data\res`

Comment: @Mighter. Yes you need create different drawables of button in both white and green color. For help as Murtaza said you can refer resources of button in "android-sdk\platforms\android-APILEVEL\data\res". I tried my self

Answer (score 0):

Default button have default 9-patch background with own margins, shadows, etc (different for different Android versions). You have to use custom background for both buttons or take one of the default 9-patch background and create similar bg for positive button.

Answer (score 0):

The default Holo Android button graphic is a PNG which purposely contains padding. If you press and hold, you'll notice a glow around the button appears...which takes up that spacing.

Answer (score 0):

The default 9 patch image for the button uses drawable padding. In order to mimic it in your own drawable you can use insets. Something like:

```
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:drawable="@drawable/bg_button_rounded_green" android:insetBottom="10dip"
     android:insetLeft="10dip" android:insetRight="10dip" android:insetTop="10dip" />
```

I'll let you figure out what the values should be.